# JavaFX: Fill parent with FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I would like to use only the FXML to make a **node fill it's parent in width**.

- I have a GridPane with column and row constraints.
- It fills the whole screen.
- The cells has the same sizes.
- I would like to put a picture into each one
- I would like the pictures to have the same width as it's parents.

From code I can make it:

```
imageView.setFitWidth(imageView.getParent().getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
```

But sometimes the *imageView.getParent().getLayoutBounds().getWidth()* call gives 0.0

I would be more glad with an FXML solution, but any other is also okay.